# How to shorten a field/name in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am sorry if this has been asked before, I have not seen a similar  question yet.

I would like to shorten a multiple attributes/fields in a shapefile in QGIS. For  example, to shorten the values like this to *A- 001-F/094-A-16* to *A- 001-F*.

I am assuming you can do this in field calculator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work

```
substr("name",0,-#)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you always want the first 8 characters of the string, use the `left(string,length)` function, like this:

```
left("name",8)
```

If want the part of the string before the slash, and some strings have different lengths before the slash, substitute `strpos("name",'/')` for the length parameter, like this:

```
left("name",strpos("name",'/'))
```